# Flyway spring boot unit Tests failures - IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, junit, flyway

I have a spring boot app that I am trying to integrate Flyway with. My app starts fine and performs the migration successfully on my local DB upon startup, but my JUnit tests fail with the message `IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext`.

My app bean creation is as follows:

```
  @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
  @Profile(value = {"default", "memory"})
  public Flyway flyway(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    Flyway flyway =
        Flyway.configure()
            .dataSource(
                dataSourceProperties.getUrl(),
                dataSourceProperties.getUsername(),
                dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
            .locations("classpath:db/migrations")
            .load();
    return flyway;
  }
```

And my test config bean is as follows:

```
  @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
  @Profile("memory")
  public Flyway flyway(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    Flyway flyway =
        Flyway.configure()
            .dataSource(dataSourceProperties.getUrl(),
                        dataSourceProperties.getUsername(),
                        dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
            .locations("classpath:db/migration")
            .load();
    return flyway;
  }
```

The flyway/JPA/spring properties for my tests are as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=some_username
spring.datasource.password=some_password

# ===============================
# JPA / HIBERNATE / FLYWAY
# ===============================

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.flyway.enabled=false
```

The reason I have enabled flyway as `false` in my test config is that I don't want my tests to be run on flyway migrations. I just want to run them on my H2 in memory DB that is created / managed by hibernate in my tests.
When I run `mvn test`, all of my tests start failing with the same error `IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext`.

Anyone have any idea what I could be missing in my Bean creation / application context for tests ?

**EDIT: Error/stack trace**:

```
[ERROR] testGetListLang(com.service.myservice.GetListLangTest)  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in com.service.myservice.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema(s) "PUBLIC" but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema(s) "PUBLIC" but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.
```

Comment: please post the stack trace of exception to know the exact line from where the exception is coming

Comment: @VikramSinghShekhawat added.

Comment: Init method is failing, see exception schema history table is missing. It suggests to use baseline.

Comment: You should inspect `FlywayAutoConfiguration`. You're manually defining your own `Flyway` bean, and Boot is respecting that. Perhaps you want a parallel `ConditionalOnProperty`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- : Any suggestions on how to do that ?

Comment: I just specified the class to examine and copy from.

Comment: Are you referring to this :
```@Conditional(value=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayDataSourceCondition.class)
 @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="spring.flyway",
                       name="enabled",
                       matchIfMissing=true)```